# How to match a regex on an array name itself in jmespath (json element string regex wildcard)

Tags: arrays, json, regex, wildcard, jmespath

How can I search for an array in a json using a regex in [jmespath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)?

Consider the following JSON document (set aside if it's poorly constructed):

```
{
  "people_in_town": [
    {"letter": "a"},
    {"letter": "b"},
  ],
  "people_with_shoes": [
    {"letter": "c"},
    {"letter": "d"},
  ],
  "people_with_town": [
    {"letter": "e"},
    {"letter": "f"},
  ],
}
```

Now, `jmespath` makes it easy to do a wildcard on all of the elements of the list such that `people_in_town[*].letter` would return `[a, b]`.

But the wildcard I want to use is a regex on the name of the arrays as follows:

```
people_*_town.letter
```

Such that it would return the contents of `people_in_town` and `people_with_town` and any array that has `people_` followed by `<some string>` followed by `_town`. The above example, of course, doesn't work.

How can I match an array in a json document with a regex using jmespath?

Comment: See also https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/add-items-to-yaml-array-only-if-defined-ansible/13568#13568

Comment: Is your use case to really do `foo_*_bar` (note this is a wildcard and not a regex, actually) or to do `foo_abc_bar OR foo_def_bar OR foo_ghi_bar`? When the first one will most likely not be possible, the second one, is definitly.

Comment: This question was created for the first, which is glaringly absent from the jmespath documentation. I used a wildcard for simplicity, but a regex would be preferred.

Comment: There is no such a thing as regex in JMESPath. Though there is a ticket open to try to fit it in: https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/213

Answer (score 1):

This is **just** covering the use case you added from your [linked question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/13564/add-items-to-yaml-array-only-if-defined-ansible/13568#13568), and not the really generic *wildcard in a key* question, that will most likely not be possible.

But in case you indeed have something to query like

```py
key in ['people_in_town', 'people_with_town']
```

So, with a finite number of know keys, then you can definitely do something like

```
[@.people_in_town, @.people_with_town][].letter
```

That would give:

```json
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "e",
  "f"
]
```

---

The main issue you'll face with a pure JMESPath approach is that the only actions you can do on keys is based on the [`keys`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys) function, and sadly is is not possible to have both the array of keys and then come back to the part to select those keys.

If you really want to resort to only JMESPath, then, you'll have to end with two pass:

1. Create the list of keys with [`keys`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#keys) and the [`starts_with`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with)/[`ends_with`](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#ends-with) functions
2. Then do a second pass to come back to the query as stated above

---

In an Ansible point of view this ends up with this ***utterly ugly*** playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug: 
        msg: >-
          {{
              data | json_query(
                "[@." ~ data | json_query(
                  "join(
                    ',@.', 
                    keys(@)[?
                      starts_with(@, 'people_') 
                      && ends_with(@, '_town')
                    ]
                  )"
                ) ~ "][].letter"
              )
          }}
      vars:
        data:
          people_in_town:
            - letter: a
            - letter: b
          people_with_shoes:
            - letter: c
            - letter: d
          people_with_town:
            - letter: e
            - letter: f
```

That yields

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - a
  - b
  - e
  - f

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So, really if I were you, I would stick to the option proposed in the answers of the [linked question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/13564/13191) and stay away from JMESPath for this specific use case.